# Android - Declare and use views in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to use kotlin for android and trying to declare Linearlayout like this:

```
internal var linlay_SuccessfulPayment : LinearLayout = null!!
internal var linlay_failPayment : LinearLayout

linlay_SuccessfulPayment = findViewById(R.id.linlay_SuccessfulPayment) as LinearLayout
linlay_failPayment = findViewById(R.id.linlay_failPayment) as LinearLayout
```

But in log I am getting this :

```
Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
                                                                         at com.example.activities.PaymentResult.<init>(Result.kt:14)
                                                                         at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1096)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3122)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7329) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Unrelated: in the edit queue, I came across a question that you voted on in triage. You made the wrong choice there. Please: study the help for triage really carefully, and avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. Please understand that your votes have consequences! I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20898974. This is (almost) zero effort homework dump. Only the OP can edit it to improve it, nobody else! Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is with nullability and this would be a good place to use the `lateinit` keyword [(documentation)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties):

```
private lateinit var linlay_SuccessfulPayment: LinearLayout
private lateinit var linlay_failPayment: LinearLayout
```

This way you define a non-nullable var but delay the initialisation, which you can do in onCreate().
You do have to initialise it before accessing it or you will get a `PropertyNotInitialisedException`.

A second option is lazy initialisation using [property delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html):

```
private var linlay_SuccessfulPayment: LinearLayout by Delegates.lazy { findViewById(R.id.linlay_SuccessfulPayment) as LinearLayout }
```

This way the view is initialised only the first time it is used and you have everything in one place.

Answer (score 4):

Just add kotlin extension in gradle.build and you don't need to initialize param:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `!!` operator checks if the value it's applied to is `null`, and if it is, it throws a `KotlinNullPointerException`; otherwise it returns the value with a non-nullable type. Writing down `null!!` is basically shorthand for `throw KotlinNullPointerException(...)`.

For Android Views (and other cases where an object is initialized in a special init method instead of the constructor), you should use the [`lateinit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties) keyword:

```
internal lateinit var linlay_SuccessfulPayment: LinearLayout
internal lateinit var linlay_failPayment: LinearLayout
```

This lets you have non-nullable properties in your `Activity` that you don't initialize when the constructor is called, but only later, in the `onCreate` method. You do however, in this case, take responsibility for initializing the variables before using them the first time, otherwise you'll get an exception at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize like below

```
internal var linlay_SuccessfulPayment : LinearLayout ?= null
internal var linlay_failPayment : LinearLayout ?= null
```

and use it like below

```
linlay_SuccessfulPayment = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linlay_SuccessfulPayment)
linlay_failPayment = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linlay_failPayment)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just starting with Kotlin and trying to learn it.
I bind views like this:

```
var myBtn: Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnMyButton) as Button
```

or

```
var btnLogin: Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnLogin)
```

Comment: i'm stupid foolish, with kotlin you don't need to bind views :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below:-

```
 var linlay_SuccessfulPayment : LinearLayout? = null
 var linlay_failPayment : LinearLayout? = null


linlay_SuccessfulPayment = findViewById(R.id.linlay_SuccessfulPayment) as LinearLayout
linlay_failPayment = findViewById(R.id.linlay_failPayment) as LinearLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` in your app level build.gradle for binding view without using the `findViewById()` boilerplate code.
e.g `linlay_failPayment.setParams() // any thing you want with only view_id`
For more information check this [kotlin-view-binding](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/taking-advantage-of-kotlin/index.html?index=..%2F..index#3)