# Button.findViewById vs Button = findViewById

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

Hey guys I am new in programming. Trying out something in Android Studio (Kotlin)
I have looked for this but didn't find an answer. `Button`

Mostly I use `Button.findViewById<Button>(R.id.Button)` but sometimes it gives me error and I have to write it like `Button = findViewById(R.id.Button) as Button`

Can someone tell me where (or what) is the difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Declare and use views in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261227/android-declare-and-use-views-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with kotlin : you don't must use findViewById. you can use direct id ex: `btnSave.text="abc"`
If code show error, you select [`btnSave`] and click [`Alt + Enter`] to import lib.

Answer (score 0):

findViewById search a View that has the Id you give inside the view you call this method with.

So when you do `Button.findViewById(R.id.btn)` it should never work because Button is a class and not an instance of view.

When you do `myButton.findViewById(R.id.btn)` it looks inside myButton, that is an instance of view, if there is a view having btn has id. If there is it return it, otherwise it returns null.

When you do `findViewById(R.id.btn)` You call this method directly from inside a custom view code. Often it's inside an Activity. Then it looks in the layout of this activity if there is a View having btn has ID.If there is it return it, otherwise it returns null.